# Better way to sort a stack / algorithm improvement + space & time reasoning

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, stack

I am trying to figure out an optimal solution for the following problem:

> Given a stack of `20` integers, sort the stack so that only
> values in range from `1` to `4` would remain in ascending order. You may only move one value
> at a time.

I have implemented an iterative & a recursive quick sort & now I'm looking for more optimal solutions. I have come up with the following so far, which runs on average approx 10x faster over 10k iterations. I am struggling to reason about space & time complexity & I'm sure there's plenty of room for a better solution.

Which sorts should I be considering? Which data types should I be considering? What's the best possible worse case time complexity **O(?)** for the given problem?

```
Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
stack.push(5);
stack.push(3);
stack.push(2);
stack.push(1);
stack.push(3);
stack.push(5);
stack.push(3);
stack.push(1);
stack.push(4);
stack.push(7);
        
HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(1, 0);
map.put(2, 0);
map.put(3, 0);
map.put(4, 0);
        
int popped;
        
while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
    popped = stack.pop();
            
    if (map.containsKey(popped)) {
        map.put(popped, map.get(popped) + 1);
    }
}
        
while (map.get(4) > 0) {
    stack.push(4);
    map.put(4, map.get(4) - 1);
}
        
while (map.get(3) > 0) {
    stack.push(3);
    map.put(3, map.get(3) - 1);
}
        
while (map.get(2) > 0) {
    stack.push(2);
    map.put(2, map.get(2) - 1);
}
        
while (map.get(1) > 0) {
    stack.push(1);
    map.put(1, map.get(1) - 1);
}
```

Comment: `move one value` leaves too much room for interpretation: Move arbitrarily within stack? Move to a second stack? Just push & pop "the" (one&only) stack?

Answer (score 2):

You're reinventing the [Counting sort algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort), which runs in linear time **O(n)**.

Instead of a `HashMap` you can use a plain array. And you definitely **don't** need this swarm of redundant `while`-loops.

Here's the description of the algorithm in pseudocode:

> `function CountingSort(input, k)`
>
> ```
> count ← array of k + 1 zeros
> output ← array of same length as input
>
> for i = 0 to length(input) - 1 do      // STEP 1
>     j = key(input[i])
>     count[j] = count[j] + 1
>
> for i = 1 to k do                      // we don't need this step
>     count[i] = count[i] + count[i - 1]
>
> for i = length(input) - 1 down to 0 do // STEP 2
>     j = key(input[i])
>     count[j] = count[j] - 1
>     output[count[j]] = input[i]
>
> return output
> ```

For your use-case you don't need the second `for`-loop where there the cumulative frequency is being calculated.

So to address the problem, we need to take the following step:

- STEP 1 is to generate a histogram of frequencies.
- STEP 2 is to iterate over frequencies backwards (i.e. starting from the very last index of the array) and push the values equal to `index` + `minValue` (in this case 1). Each value should be pushed the number of times equal to its frequency.

Here's an implementation:

```
final int min = 1;
final int max = 4;

int[] freq = new int[max - min + 1]; // histogram, i.e. array of frequencies of values in range [min, max]
        
// STEP 1: generating a histogram

while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
    int next = stack.pop();
    if (next >= min && next <= max) freq[next - min]++; // calculating the frequency of each element
}
    
// STEP 2: populating the stack in sorted order
        
for (int i = freq.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    while (freq[i] > 0) {
        stack.push(i + min);
        freq[i]--;
    }
}

return stack;
```

If you want to use the `HashMap`, fine, you can apply the **same algorithm**, just don't create redundant loops.

Regarding the time complexity in both cases it would be **linear** as I've said before. Array would perform slightly better, but more importantly it gives you a better feeling of the internal mechanics of the algorithm.

```
final int min = 1;
final int max = 4;
        
Map<Integer, Integer> freq = new HashMap<>(); // histogram, i.e. array of frequencies of values in range [min, max]

// STEP 1: generating a histogram
        
while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
    int next = stack.pop();
    if (next >= min && next <= max) 
        freq.merge(next, 1, Integer::sum); // calculating the frequency of each element
}
    
// STEP 2: populating the stack in sorted order
    
for (int i = max; i >= min; i--) {
    int count = freq.get(i);
    while (count > 0) {
        stack.push(i + min);
        count--;
    }
}
        
return stack;
```

***Sidenote:*** class `java.util.Stack` is legacy and **not** encouraged to be used. When you need an implementation of Stack data structure in Java, use classes that implement [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Deque.html) interface.

Comment: I should have explained myself better, its a plate stacking problem so I don't think counting sort would be suitable as you would need to lift multiple plates at a time?

Comment: @riverside96 How can remove multiple element from the stack at a time? I'm not quite understood this phrase. Can you share complete code? If you're asking is it possible to apply the counting sort to sorting the contents of the stack - then the answer is yes, you need to **empty out** the whole stack, walk the all steps of the algorithm and populate the stack again.

Comment: @riverside96 Or maybe the problem description is incomplete? If it's a coding challenge (or something like that), then please provide the *original description*.

Comment: In the counting sort the array values are sorted in place. If you imagine the array to be a pile of plates stacked vertically, sorting them in placer would not be possible if we can not move more than one plate at a time.

Comment: Sorry? I don't follow.

Comment: @riverside96 Wait, can you post in the question your **code** in which you're populating the map? Use *edit* button or this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74246669/edit). If there are some constraint regarding to how elements should be *removed from/added on* the stack, describe them as well.

Comment: The map is being populated within while(!stack.isEmpty()){

Comment: @riverside96 I've updated the answer with the implementation and description. And **note** Counting sort in **not** an in-place sorting algorithm because it requires an auxiliary storage.

Comment: Thank you! It does execute quite a bit faster. The only issue I see with using an array is that if the given valid sizes are not in sequence ie (2, 4, 5, 7) then this would add to the complexity, though I didn't specify that!

Comment: Do you have any tips as to what I should consider when calculating the space & time complexity of mine & your improved solution? Also why is an array preferential here, would a hashmap not have an access of O(1) at this size? Sorry to be a pain. Just trying to get a grasp on things.

Comment: @riverside96 You should not only care about the time complexity of the code, but also think of its maintainability. What if you would need numbers in range `[1,25]`? It would not be wise to clatter the code with **25** `while`-loops. Obviously, you need a **single** enclosing `for`-loop instead. Both `HashMap` and array can serve as a mean of calculating the frequencies. Would it be justifiable to use array over map when there are gaps between the target numbers, depends on particular case. You can play around with this idea, write some code and ask a separate question.

Comment: Hang fire... if step one is done n times, & step2 is done >n times , could that be be considered O(n2) == O(n)

Comment: I can't thank you enough. You've given me some great insight & definitely some food for thought. I have to reason about time & space complexity of different solutions & justify data structure choice.

Comment: @riverside96  Regarding the time complexity - first of all get familiar with the basics https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity The only **uniform tip**: evaluate how many times each operation is executed and what is the cost for each operation

Comment: @riverside96 Don't muddy the water) The time complexity is linear. `1/3 * N`, `2 * N`, `any_constant_number * N` all are the **same** as `N`. Constants are **not** taken into account while evaluating the algorithm's time complexity.